# How can I open a page and assign its datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

my question is relatively easy, I guess. 
I have a page to display my data. On a click on a button I want to open a new page with the datacontext of an element 2 layers above the datacontext of the current element.

Explanation:

My ViewModel is a class (ViewModelContainer) that contains more ViewModels. One is a summary of values and one is the detailed view of that.

```
public class SummaryViewModel
{
     public int somevalue; // is a property
     public ObservableCollection<SummarizedItems> items; // is a property
}

public class DetailsViewModel
{
     public int someOthervalue; // is a property
     public int stuffA; // is a property
     public int stuffB; // is a property
}

public class ViewModelContainer : ViewModelBase
{
     private SummaryViewModel _sum;
     public SummaryViewModel sum { }  // is a property

     private DetailsViewModel _det;
     public DetailsViewModel det { }  // is a property
}
```

The View where I can press a button is bound to the value of the ObservableCollection of SummaryViewModel.
Everything is fine till now. When I press the button, a new page, showing the details should be opened. I use an ICommand to handle the click, and pass it the details view as a CommandParameter.

```
<Button Name="OpenDetailsButton" Command="{Binding Path=ACommand}" CommandParameter="{DynamicResource Details}"
```

I define a page as a resource in the same file, where the datacontext is still ViewModelContainer.

```
<pages:DetailsViewPage DataContext="{Binding Path=det }"  x:Key="Details"/>
```

The page opens, but the datacontext is not available. I get the following error:

```
  System.Windows.Data Error: 3 : Cannot find element that provides DataContext.
```

Has anyone an idea how I could open the details view and providing the datacontext? I cannot move the DetailsViewModel to another class, because it is only possible to update it there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by creating a helper to go up the visual tree and use the datacontext of the element i needed. Thanks for everybody who tried to help :)

the method looks like this:

```
    public static UIELEMENT FindUiElementUpVisualTree(DependencyObject initial)
    {
        DependencyObject current = initial;

        while (current != null && current.GetType() != typeof(UIELEMENT))
        {
            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        }
        return current as UIELEMENT;
    }
```

where UIELEMENT is the object you are looking for e.g. a window or a button or something.

Answer (score 0):

usually views and viewmodels have a one to one relationship. In this case it seems like there is a many to one relationship. How about a DetailsPageViewModel?